# How to Ignore returning a key value in Python Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

i need to write a function create_dictionary(filename) that reads the named file and returns a dictionary mapping from object names to occurrence counts (the number of times the particular object was guessed). For example, given a file mydata.txt containing the following:

```
abacus
calculator
modern computer
abacus
modern computer
large white thing
modern computer
```

Here's my program, and it works fine for non-empty text files.

```
from collections import Counter
def create_dictionary(filename):
"""Cool Program"""
   keys = Counter()
   s = open(filename,'r').read().strip()
   keys = (Counter(s.split('\n')))

dictionary = create_dictionary('mydata.txt')
for key in dictionary:
print(key + ': ' + str(dictionary[key]))
return keys
```

Out will be as:

```
{'abacus': 2, 'calculator': 1, 'modern computer': 3, 'large white thing': 1}
```

When I have an empty file (eg. blank.txt), the function must ignore any and all blank lines. So, the print statement must return a blank. But I am getting ': 1' no matter what I tried. And oh, here are some simple constraints:
Here are some constraints:

- You may assume the given file exists, but it may be empty (i.e. containing no lines).
- Keys must be inserted into the dictionary in the order in which they appear in the input file.
- Leading and trailing whitespace should be stripped from object names
- Empty object names (e.g. blank lines or lines with only whitespace) should be ignored.

Any advise?

Comment: Fix your indentation for starters

Answer (score 2):

```
lines = open(filename,'r').readlines()
keys = Counter([line.strip() for line in lines if line.strip()])
```

Comment: Thanks John. I always suspected readlines to be an integral component. It works now. And I understand the mechanism.

Comment: @Pamela readlines should have no impact here. You could easily leave it out. The only difference is `readlines` forces the file to be read immediately. If you leave it out python will read the file in a lazy manner. This might have an impact if the file was large, for a small file its not so significant.